# How to use global variables across multiple .py files and their functions

Tags: global-variables

My python project has a number of .py files

1. Main.py         frontend menu
2. Globals.py  contains a bunch of variables including pandas dataframe variables
3. Getdata.py  reads the data into pandas dataframes from excel
4. Printdata.py    manipulate and print the dataframe data – multiple functions

My question is – what is the best way to allow access to the dataframe data across all of the .py files and their functions?  I want all the functions in the .py files to be able to modify the dataframe data.

I have tried many ways of declaring global variables but have not been successful as yet.
My latest effort was to import from my globals.py file

Comment: In which way have you _not been successful_ with your _latest effort_?